# What is the probability that the most common 3 results of 12 equally likely outcomes are selected by at least 11 of a sample of size 22?

Tags: combinatorics

For a illustrative example:

22 people are being sorted into 12 teams. 12 colored balls are placed in a hat. Each player draws a ball from the hat (with replacement) to figure out which team they are on. When the 3 largest teams are counted (random selection among ties for 3rd), **the total of these teams is 11 or higher**. What are the chances that this is the case?

Here's what I've gotten so far.

I've established that the maximum number of configurations for the teams is (33 choose 11). I know that I need to select for the largest 3 which can be chosen in (13 choose 2) ways. I'm unsure how to check if the largest 3 teams have 11 or more players.

This problem actually relates to a non-mathematical query I had regarding 12 possible outcomes selected by a sample of 22 persons. I have only foundational mathematical knowledge.

---

Source of the question:

In [Dungeons and Dragons](http://dnd.wizards.com/dungeons-and-dragons/what-is-dd), there are 12 classes players can select. While the chance a player selects them is obviously not random in the real world, a chatizen friend of mine was contemplating a combinatorics question regarding a specific outcome of one of the games he is running. In particular, 11 of the first 22 applicants chose the same 3 classes (Wizard, Fighter, and Paladin). Then, after more applications came in (checking later on during the conversation), 50% of the 28 applications were still these 3. So we wanted a more generalized approach, prompting a question here. This conversation was in a StackExchange chat room, a bookmark of which can be found [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/use-case).

Comment: How do you deal with situations where there are only 3 teams or less? I guess when there are exactly 3 teams then this is part of your desired event. But how about the 22 people forming only 2 teams or just all in the same color (team)? Do you count them in or out?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin that would count as a success case. Although the chances of that are so finite it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Counting problems of this kind can be difficult.  An exact count can be had by modelling the team selections as a Markov chain/state transitions.

Each of 22 players gets assigned a "color" randomly assigned from the twelve possibilities.  If the outcomes are considered to be assignments of 22 players to twelve teams, there will be $12^{22}$ possibilities.

How many of these satisfy the condition that in the end at least eleven players belong to not more than three of the teams? Or on the contrary, how many outcomes do not have more than ten players combined among three teams?

Counting all $12^{22}$ outcomes would be time-consuming:

$$ 12^{22} \approx 10^{23.74} $$

But there is a way to trim down the outcome space to just the *integer partitions* of $n\le 22$ into at most twelve parts.  As the tabulation below shows, this is a much more manageable number of outcomes to track:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & p_{\le 12}(n) & n & p_{\le 12}(n) \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 12 & 77 \\
2 & 2 & 13 & 100 \\
3 & 3 & 14 & 133 \\
4 & 5 & 15 & 172 \\
5 & 7 & 16 & 224 \\
6 & 11 & 17 & 285 \\
7 & 15 & 18 & 366 \\
8 & 22 & 19 & 460 \\
9 & 30 & 20 & 582 \\
10 & 42 & 21 & 725 \\
11 & 56 & 22 & 905 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

**Table 1.** Integer partitions $p_{\le 12}(n)$ of $n$ with at most $12$ parts

However not all partitions of this kind are equally likely.  The bookkeeping will need to keep track of *non-uniform* probabilities for the $905$ outcomes.  This is enough state information to tell us when some combination of three teams has eleven or more players.

I did a bit of Prolog coding to get the probability values as floating point approximations, and the result is about $0.488104643$.

Here is a sketch of the probability state transition process.  We identify the states with counts adding to $n=1,\ldots,22$ (*partitions* with at most twelve parts of $n$), starting with the one state for $n=1$ where:

$$ 1 = 1+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0  $$

This "initial" state is reached with probability $1.0$ after the first colored ball is chosen, although the underlying color choice is not shown (and could be any one of the twelve colors).

Next the second ball is drawn, giving two possible states (partitions of $2$ with at most twelve parts).  The probabilities of the two states are *unequal* at this second stage, because it is more likely a different color will be drawn than it is the same color:

$$ 2 = 2+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0  $$

$$ 2 = 1+1+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0  $$

Thus these states have respective probabilities at step $2$ of $1/12$ and $11/12$.

The rules for propagating the probabilities from one step to the next are straightforward but tedious.  The number of states grows inexorably, and many of the states will have eventually have insignificantly small probabilities.  But the combined probability of all states at any one step is $1.0$, and there are no subtraction cancellations (which makes our floating point computation quite robust and reliable).

After I polish my Prolog code and commenting of it a little, I'll push it up to GitHub and give a link to it here.  Curiously I found that all but $58$ of the $905$ final states give eleven in the largest three parts, but the collective probability of these states is (as already noted) slightly less than $50$%.

Comment: [We tried that approach](https://ghostbin.com/paste/zss7b), and the number we got (89.17%) is different than the [number we got experimentally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W94pc.png) (48.84%) as you predicted (since they aren't equally likely). Is there a way to apply a weight to each of the 905 solutions to correct this?

Comment: Propagating the probabilities as outlined in my original Answer, I get that the chance of eleven or more in the three biggest "teams" is $0.488104643$, which is quite close to your simulation value.  I gather from your figure $89.17$% that all but 98 of the 905 partitions would meet that threshold.

Comment: When I run through the possible partitions, I get that all but 58 of the 905 partitions meet the threshold (at least eleven members of top 3 biggest groupings).

Comment: I can't remember which groupings we calculated worked or not, but thanks for all your work on this :) Using the partitions like that was one of our ideas but we really didn't have the knowhow to fully execute that process.